# Check the below logic from RecyclerView Adapter. is there any thing wrong?

Tags: collections, android-recyclerview

I'm replacing items as much possible then either adding or removing the items based on condition.

```
public void addFileListEntries(List<FileListEntry> fileListEntries) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(mFileListEntries.size(), fileListEntries.size()); i++) {
        mFileListEntries.set(i, fileListEntries.get(i));
        notifyItemChanged(i);
    }
    if (mFileListEntries.size() > fileListEntries.size()) {
        ArrayList<FileListEntry> subList = new ArrayList<>(mFileListEntries
                .subList(fileListEntries.size(), mFileListEntries.size() - 1));
        mFileListEntries.removeAll(subList);
        notifyItemRangeRemoved(fileListEntries.size(),
                fileListEntries.size() + subList.size() - 1);
    } else if (mFileListEntries.size() < fileListEntries.size()) {
        ArrayList<FileListEntry> subList = new ArrayList<>(fileListEntries
                .subList(mFileListEntries.size(), fileListEntries.size() - 1));
        mFileListEntries.addAll(subList);
        notifyItemRangeInserted(mFileListEntries.size(),
                mFileListEntries.size() + subList.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

Here `mFileListEntries` is the DataSet for the adpter and `fileListEntries` is the new DataSet.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `RecyclerView` implementation in Android will effectively handle this by default. You can just assign `fileListEntries` to `mFileListEntries` and call `notifyDataSetChanged` (in the main thread). If you don't want to change the `mFileListEntries` object, then just clear it and `addAll` `fileListEntries` before calling `notifyDataSetChanged`.

In fact, your first loop calling `notifyItemChanged` many times could cause more damage. `notifyItemChanged`, `notifyItemRangeRemoved` and `notifyItemRangeInserted` are to be used only when you know the exact subset of items added/removed/changed.

Comment: Thanks. Actually main intention was doing like this is to animate the items of RecyclerView.

Comment: @Prasanna, Do you mean animating all the entries when the list is updated? Or are you interested in animating only changed items?

Comment: Yes.. Exactly. I did as above animations are ok, but items in the list are misplacing

Comment: @ArunBabuASP Off topic .contact with me